# Redefinition warnings with responsive webdesign

Tags: html, css, validation, warnings, w3c

I get a lot of redefinition warnings like these when running my site through the W3C CSS Validator:

```
.fa.fa-shopping-cart    Redefinition of font-size
.fa.fa-shopping-cart    Redefinition of height
.fa.fa-shopping-cart    Redefinition of line-height
.fa.fa-shopping-cart    Redefinition of width
```

The script for .fa.fa-shopping-cart looks like this:

```
.fa.fa-shopping-cart 
{
    color: #81D742;
    background-color: #F7F7F7;
    border: 2px solid #DCDCDC;
    display: inline-block;
    text-align:center;
    padding: 0px;
}

.fa.fa-shopping-cart:hover 
{
color: #7BAE23
}
```

And for each @media rule for different devices I've added different values for the .fa.fa-shopping-cart like this:

```
@media only screen and (min-width: 1024px)
.fa.fa-shopping-cart
{
    font-size: 4em;
    border-radius: 120px;
    height: 120px;
    line-height: 120px;
    width: 120px;
}
```

I therefore understand why I'm getting the redefinition warnings, 
but I'm wondering if it's possible to give the elements different 
values for different devices without getting these warnings?

Comment: iMHO, these warnings are good in that , you can review your code for mistakes you might have made and correct it. Why should you be worries about this?

Comment: But aren't these mistakes that I've made and should be able to correct? I have a total of 3067 warnings and most of them are redefinition warnings like the ones above. It would be wonderful to clean them out.

Comment: Redefinition of an attribute, say in a media query, is often inevitable & the warnings from CSS validator regarding this can be safely neglected.

Comment: So it's basically not possible to give an element different values for different devices without redefining them?

Comment: At least with pure css, no. You write a jquery  to do this.

Comment: Okay. Thank you so much.